# no lwjgl64 in java.library.path

Tags: java, ubuntu, minecraft

I'm trying to run a game in linux. The game launcher loads up properly but when the actual game has to load up, it doesn't. When i check the log files it says the following.

```
[2020-06-22 04:17:17.233] [info]          [OUTPUT] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
[2020-06-22 04:17:17.235] [info]          [OUTPUT] 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at IIlIlIlIIlIIlIlllllIIlIlI.llIIllllIllllllIllIIIllIl(Minecraft:3148)
    at IIIIlIllllIIlIIIIlIlIIIII.IlllIIIlIIIIIIIlIllIIllIl(Minecraft:39)
    at Start.main(Minecraft:13)
```

it says something about not having the lwjgl64 file. The launcher is run through a .appimage file. I'm running Ubuntu Linux and im using Java 8 and 11, but i have set Java 8 to be the default version.

How do i fix this error?

Comment: Uhh, Minecraft Java Edition isn't supposed to use an AppImage. Are you sure you didn't download a virus masquerading as a cracked version?

Comment: im using a pvp client called Lunar Client, it's 100% legit. But don't worry, i know how to fix it, but i cant since i cant access the JVM of the launcher

Comment: Lunar Client's FAQ says "We do not currently offer Linux support to the client." Thus, I conclude that you did indeed download a fake one.